# IronPython Microsoft.Scripting Exception

Tags: exception, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to run IronPython code with c#.
I created a simple console application (.net 4) and added IronPython.dll , IronPython.Modules.dll and Microsoft.Scripting and wrote the next code -

```
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptRuntime runtime = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
            ScriptEngine engine = runtime.GetEngine("py");

            engine.Execute("print 'hello!'");
        }
    }
}
```

While trying to run this , I get an exception -

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException :
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Scripting, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture
>   =neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The syste m
>   cannot find the file specified.    at
>   Core.LanguageProvider.Python..ctor(Stream
>   stream)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, O bject[] args,
>   SignatureStruct& signature,
>   RuntimeType declaringType)    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Ob ject[] args,
>   SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeType
>   declaringType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, B inder binder, Object[]
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags
>   bindingAttr, Binder bin der, Object[]
>   args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binde
>   r binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo
>   culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Object[] args)    at
>   Core.LanguageRuntime.RegisterLanguageProvider(Type
>   providerType) in D:\cod
>   e\CodeRunner\Core\LanguageRuntime.cs:line
>   30    at Test.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   D:\code\CodeRunner\Test\Program.cs:lin
>   e 19 Press any key to continue . . .

I really , don`t know what to do , searched at google and don`t find a solution.
I will be glad to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whic version of iron python are you using ? The syntax you show seems belong to an older version, now you should have something like:

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
```

anyway [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx) seems to be really accurate on pointing the correct reference to use. Anyway, ensure you have the [latest IronPython version.](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks,fixed it out . I have another problem when trying to run both ironruby code and ironpython,I am getting this error, what to do?

Comment: I did not understand if the reply was working for you or not. Anyway you should be able to run both IronPython and IronRuby if you use two version depending on the same DLR. Unfortunately I've only experience with IronPython so I can't say anything more about Ruby.

Comment: It worked for me. I can`t run both because IronPython uses Microsoft.Scripting version 2.6 and IronRuby using Microsoft.Scripting version 1.1, what to do?

Comment: maybe posting a question specific on this could help. As I said I've no direct experience with IronRuby, sorry.